# How to optimize particle emitter render FPS (in openGL) on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, particles

I have tried these:

1. Make the particle image smaller, now using a 8x8 one. I just don't know how to make it even further smaller because I need a fading circle. 4x4 is too small
2. Lower the particle numbers, now is 40 but if even lower is too low.

Is there any other way I can do to make it better?

I saw many cool games (like Bejewled Blitz) have very good effects and it seems they are using very smooth images / many particles. Is there some other way I can make the FPS better?

Thanks for all the kind up-votes and answers! Here are some updates:

1. I am already using **cocos2d-x** with **OpenGL**
2. I currently use a commercial software called **Particle Designer**
3. I am testing on iTouch 4 while all other games are running without any problems. I tried to switch to other devices and the problem remains.
4. The current FPS is 25-30 with a particle effect, and I can surely feel it (a little laggy). When there're more particle effects on the screen, it's even worse (FPS can be only 10)
5. I tried many ways and found shape of the particle element is a very key bottleneck but it's really hard to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you can do is to start using some game engine which supports optimized particle system.  I don't have a good overview of what's available for iOS, but there must be some free and open source engines. For example [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) has particles.

But if choose do that yourself, then normally reducing number of draw calls and state changes makes rendering faster. If you have different textures you can merge them into a [texture altas](http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/03/Using-texture-atlases). This would allow you to merge all the particles into one vertex buffer and render all of them at once.

Your number (40 particles) seems very very low. Are you sure the particles are the bottleneck? Normally optimizing rendering performance is a very difficult and time consuming process. One needs to make many experiments, use different tools and try out various approaches before it's clear what the bottleneck is and how to make it faster. Problems could be of general nature and very much hardware specific. Something that works faster on one device is slower on another.

Unless you do that for educational reasons, I would strongly advise to reuse existing solutions with man-years of work put into them to make them faster.

**Update:** Looking at your edit, I have to say, I'm struggling to offer any suggestions. Maybe the sprites are too big and you max out the fillrate. Or shader on them is too complex and it takes a long time to draw even a few of them.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo, I updated the answer. I don't have many ideas. Maybe you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks very much for the updates. I am wondering, whether I can draw the shape with native API rather than an image?